# Correct way of using Bind

Tags: javascript, ajax

What is the most correct way of using Bind. I have used like this and it is working but interested in finding the best possible option

```
ObjectProcessor = function (pathList) {
    this.data = null;
}
ObjectProcessor.prototype = {
    callServer: function () {
        ajaxObject.Get("api/Path", this.callReceive.bind(this), null, this.callError.bind(this), this.callComplete.bind(this));
    },
    callReceive: function (source) {

        this.data = source;
    },
    callComplete: function (source) {
        // do something
    },
    callError: function (source) {
        // Show Error
    }
};
```

Comment: using the ajax callback arguments instead of "this" in your handler, me thinks you wouldn't need bind.

Comment: The syntax is correct, but the way the functions are called shouldn't it work just fine without `bind`

Comment: @adeneo we don't know how ajaxObject is calling the functions.  So it likely wont work correctly without binding.

Comment: @dandavis I was going to say something similar, the correct way to use bind is to code in a way so that `this` is already set to what it should be. Otherwise it is unintuitive; sometimes you just can't beat it though.

Comment: @StevenWexler - Ah, that's right, then it seems fine to me.

Comment: This seems fine to me.  Watch out for browser comaptibiltiy.  You may need to use a polyfill for certain browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility

Comment: The function would not work without using bind or wrapping the call in function. As it stands now it is working. I was asking for the best or most correct way of passing a function argument in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bind` when you need a new instance of a function whose `this` value is explicitly set to whatever you passed in with the `bind()` call.

> ECMAScript 5 defines an additional method called bind(). The bind() method creates a new function instance whose this value is
>   bound to the value that was passed into bind().
>   (Zakas, *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, 3rd ed.*, 146).

The main advantage seems to be using `bind()` in place of closures where multiple closures would make the code hard to read. See p. 738 "Function Binding" in Zakas for more. Briefly,

> Function binding involves creating a function that calls another
>   function with a specific this value and with specific arguments. This
>   technique is often used in conjunction with callbacks and event
>   handlers to preserve code execution context while passing functions
>   around as variables.
>   (Zakas, 738)
>
> Bound functions are useful whenever a function pointer must be passed
>   as a value and that function needs to be executed in a particular
>   context. They are most commonly used for event handlers and with
>   setTimeout() and setInterval(). However, bound functions have more
>   overhead than regular functions — they require more memory and are
>   slightly slower because of multiple function calls — so it’s best to
>   use them only when necessary.
>   (Zakas, 740-41)